# Can I use templates here?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following piece of code:

```
int CreatePropertiesDialog(int type, void *object)
{
    if( type == 1 )
    {
        ClassA *a = static_cast<ClassA *>( object );
        // build the properties dialog
    }
    if( type == 2 )
    {
        ClassB *b = static_cast<ClassB *>( object );
        // build the properties dialog
    }
    // display the properties dialog
}
```

However, the use of `void*` type sounds very ugly.

Can this code be improved by using template? Or maybe some other means?

Comment: If `type` can be `constexpr` then you can use a template. If it has to be runtime then perhaps look at `std::variant` implementations for C++11, such as boost.

Comment: Or even just overload the method and then call a common `displayDialog` method.

Comment: It seems like dynamic polymorphism (inheritance and virtual functions) would be better suited (assuming the type is only known at runtime).

Comment: If you only intend to process classes `ClassA` and `ClassB`, why not just make one `CreatePropertiesDialog(ClassA *object);` and an overload `CreatePropertiesDialog(ClassB *object);`?

Comment: @interjay, could you please put some pseudo-code? Also ClassA and ClassB do not depend on any other library - they are just generic C++ code. So no GUI display code there.

Comment: @GovindParmar, at this point it just ClassA and ClassB. Don't know how many others will be displayed.

Comment: @Igor In this case you also have to deal with so many `if`s, so it does not become worse with overloading.

Comment: The usual C++ approach here is to declare a base class which A and B extend, and pass pointer to your base class around instead of void*. Then, you make type a virtual member function that returns the type. Better yet have a virtual method to do the CreatePropertiesDialog() functionality in each case.

Answer (score 5):

You can ditch the `type` parameter altoghether and have two methods, one for `ClassA` or one for `ClassB`. Like this:

```
int CreatePropertiesDialog(ClassA *a)
{
        // build the properties dialog
        DialogConf conf = ...
        return displayDialog(conf);   
}


int CreatePropertiesDialog(ClassB *b)
{
        // build the properties dialog
        DialogConf conf = ...
        return displayDialog(conf);   
}

int displayDialog(DialogConf conf) {
    // ...
}
```

Or, you can have `ClassA` and `ClassB` responsible for building the configuration by each having a method that returns a `DialogConf` that contains the configuration and then pass it to `displayDialog`.

Comment: if I ditch the parameter, how do displayDialog knows what to display? ClassA and ClassB do not depend on the GUI, they are generic C++ classes.

Comment: Your code gave the impression that they were just needed to compose some configuration. If they have nothing to do with the GUI, of course, the second solution does not apply. In the first solution, it's the two `createPropertyDialog`s that knows how to compose the configuration (just like in your example), and since the two overloaded methods know what type of parameter they are receiving they can act accordingly. Hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on how you call the code and what is the available data.

For example, if you have a bunchof `void*`:

```
void** objects = get_objects();

CreatePropertiesDialog(type, objects[1]);
```

Then your input is all `void*`. Must must process it as is or refactor the code to not use void pointers.

If you have locals or variables of known types, then overloading might be appropriated:

```
int CreatePropertiesDialog(ClassA*) {
    // ...
}

int CreatePropertiesDialog(ClassB*) {
    // ...
}
```

Without more information about what you have as input data  it's hard to have a more precise answer.